AWS elastic beanstalk suspended status
I'm having an issue in my AWS env.
Everything was working fine and suddenly from nowhere the status of enhanced health check is returning suspended (Gray), permissions are correct and instance profile is correct is well, does anybody faced a similar issue?
I tried Recreate the role and instance profile and all still the same.
